# Add Stack Exchange Recent Questions to a wordpress sidebar?

Tags: plugins, sidebar, stackoverflow

So my question is what is the easiest way to go about scraping a Stack Exchange forum "recent questions" and display them in the side bar of a wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

Use an RSS feed widget and grab the RSS feed of the SE site. In the case of this site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/feeds/

Answer (score 0):

Use the stack exchange API http://api.stackexchange.com/docs along with WordPress' HTTP related functions:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API
- `wp_remote_get()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get
- `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body

... and finally [cached](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) for good measure.